# CSS (/ Wordpress) White Space property behaving strangely

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Despite setting the "white-space" property to my paragraphs to "normal" in CSS, the breaks in some of my lines are spacing really strangely. Does anyone have an idea at to what may be the cause? [Here is an example of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ8ST.png).

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can we see some HTML and CSS for this?

Answer (score 0):

these lines are prob. seperated by different p elements.

```
word-break: break-all;
word-break: break-word;
word-break: keep-all;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
hyphens: manual;
hyphens: auto;
line-break: loose;
line-break: strict;
line-break: anywhere;
text-wrap: balance;
```

these are some styles can apply to change break points in text.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have found and resolved the issue, which I have posted as an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Upon investigation, it turns out my wordpress had been adding in random `&nbsp` breaks to my `<p>` elements. I found a solution to this in another thread which involves adding the following code to my `functions.php` file:

```
function replace_content($content) {
    $content = htmlentities($content, null, 'utf-8');
    $content = str_replace("&nbsp;", " ", $content);
    $content = html_entity_decode($content);
return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','replace_content', 999999999);
```

[Credits to 'Bruno' https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29702/wordpress-automatically-adding-nbsp]